# privateGPT не хочет отвечать по моим документам. как быть?

Tags: gpt

Всем привет.
Такая проблема.
Есть privateGPT суть которого на основе модели отвечать на вопросы по вашим документам локально.
Что бы я не делал, любые модели скачивал, документы делал и на русском и на английском но если загрузить более 1 документа то ответ поступает точно не от них а от тех данных что модель сама знает или же с инета что мне не нужно.
Подскажи варианты может быть есть какие по примеру privatGPT чтобы на основе моих документов gpt или ещё что то отвечало на мои вопросы.
Как быть в такой ситуации?
Всем заранее спасибо!